# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows' - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Below is my code. I do not understand why it has error: ttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Could someone advise me on a way to correct it?

```
a=pd.DataFrame(index=['D1','D2','D3','D4'], columns=[x for x in range(0,10)])
a.loc[:]=5
for index,row in a.loc['D1',].iterrows():
    for col in a.columns:
      if a.at[index,col]>0:
        print(True)
```

Comment: Because `.iterrows` is a property of a `DataFrame`, but you have a `Series`.

Comment: maybe you are looking for `iteritems` ?  Maybe not though since you appear to be trying to iterate over columns after that.  My guess is .loc isn't doing what you think it's doing

Comment: Why would you use `iterrows` when you're looking at a single row?

Answer (score 1):

Use the dataframe as such, not a single row:

```py
a=pd.DataFrame(index=['D1','D2','D3','D4'], columns=[x for x in range(0,10)])
a.loc[:]=5
for index,row in a.iterrows():
    for col in a.columns:
      if a.at[index,col]>0:
        print(True)
```

Comment: What if OP is only interested in the row corresponding to index=D1?

Comment: With two for loops, the variables used here and the way of coding, single row could not be processed, I believe so.